# Correct way to signal stream complete

Tags: gulp

I've created a function to pipe data into a file and output individual files for each line of data. However, there are 35K lines of data to compile and although the code below signals "done" after about 5 mins, the files are still processing. I can't start the next function until this one is completed so I need to know when it has actually finished.

```
function createLocations(done) {
if (GENERATE_LOCATIONS) {

    for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
        var location = locations[i],
           fileName = 'location-' + location.area.replace(/ +/g, '-').replace(/'+/g, '').replace(/&+/g, 'and').toLowerCase() + '-' + location.town.replace(/ +/g, '-').replace(/'+/g, '').replace(/`+/g, '').replace(/&+/g, 'and').toLowerCase();
        gulp.src('./templates/location-template.html')
            .pipe($.rename(fileName + ".html"))      
            .pipe(gulp.dest('./tmp/'));
        }
    }
    done();
    console.log('Creating '+locations.length+' Files Please Wait...');
}
```

The function runs for a further 15mins after it has signalled done. Appreciate any help to detect the actual completion of the function.

Many thanks!

Comment: Have you tried using the gulp util .on 'finish' or 'end' function.

Comment: How about gulp.src('...', done) ...pipes...done(); So at the end of each gulp.src to signal each stream is done.  I think you have to signal each stream via cb or return, etc.

Comment: Make that gulp.src('...',  function( done) { ...pipes...done();}